# How to change desktop theme using a .sh file? (RASPBERRYPI OS)

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I have been playing around with raspberrypi os and the hardware its self. But besides i have a question i wan to ask, How do you change the desktop theme of raspberrypi os using a `.sh` file? Or is it even possible to do?

Comment: what is your understanding of `.sh` files?

Comment: @jsotola `.sh` file = `shell` file

Comment: that's part of it ... what is inside the shell file?

Comment: There is nothing in the `.sh` file, I am asking how you can change the desktop theme using  a `.sh file`.

Comment: you are limiting your chances of success by asking the wrong question  ... `.sh` file contains any number of Bash commands (if you use Bash) ... Bash commands are what you would type at a command prompt in a terminal window, but placed in a file for automatic execution .... search `How do you change the desktop theme of raspberrypi os using CLI?` (command line interface)

Comment: Sure, but is there any command for terminal or `CLI`  that would chage the desktop theme? :)